# C# Webapi HelpPage Request Model Customization

Tags: c#, model, request, customization, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have created my WebAPI controllers' documentation using HelpPage. I have following model in my web api.

```
public class InfoModel
{
    [Required]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string title { get; set; }

    public string status { get; set; }

    public string created_at { get; set; }
}
```

HelpPage renders InfoModel on help page like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "title": "Sample string 2",
   "status": "Sample string 3",
   "created_at": "Sample string 4"
}
```

Using [Required] attribute from [Model Validation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) and I want to highlight properties having [Required] attribute. How can I customize HelpPage MVC plugin to bold "**id**" and "**title**", so that user may know that these attributes are **REQUIRED**:

{

"**id**": 1,

"**title**": "Sample string 2",

"status": "Sample string 3",

"created_at": "Sample string 4"

}

I understand Jquery/CSS but for that HelpPage MVC should render HTML contents with some marking for [Required] attributes so that JS/CSS may style them differently on client side. I am expecting some modifications in **Areas.HelpPage.ObjectGenerator** class that is responsible for generating HTML for InfoModel.

Comment: Apply some css? font-weight: bold;

Comment: Apply CSS to what? I mean how to let CSS know to distinguish between required and optional parameters?

Comment: You'll have to define what parameters are required and optional.

Comment: @theGeekster What Sam is saying (albeit it's quite vague) is that the HelpPages just write out a Razor view like any other in your MVC project. Have a look at the `Index.cshtml` generated in your `Areas/HelpPage` folder to see the DOM structure generated - then include any CSS you might require. As mentioned, you might need jQuery to add classes based on the text content of the API list

Comment: I have added my sample InfoModel class code above that is annotating key parameters with [Required] attribute. This is what I want to display on HelpPage in some way to let user know that these parameters are [Required]. I understand Jquery/CSS but for that HelpPage MVC should render HTML contents with some marking for [Required] attributes so that JS/CSS may style them differently on client side. I am expecting some modifications in Areas.HelpPage.ObjectGenerator class that is responsible for generating HTML for InfoModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using latest version of Web API, then you get helpful information regarding data annotation attributes like `Required` etc.

Example:
[image]

Comment: What version exactly does this? By Web API you mean latest HelpPage or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to apply css to the `id` and `title`:

```
$('foo').css("font-weight","Bold");
```